# iOS How can I get the battery level of the connected bluetooth device

Tags: ios, bluetooth, battery

AS you know , iPhone can get the battery level of connected bluetooth devices(not ble devices) and show it on the status bar . How can I get this information programmatically ?

Comment: You can't except if the device has a way to tell it when you ask for it. In a few projects I have, I set a NSTimer asking for the battery every 5 seconds, sending a message according to the device specifications (and this message was different on each products).

Answer (score 0):

As I know, For classic BT, only devices contain headset profile can.

check this
https://developer.apple.com/hardwaredrivers/BluetoothDesignGuidelines.pdf

Comment: Assuming the BT Classic device provides this information, is there a public API for reading the value? I know the battery level is displayed by the OS, but can't find out if the value is available for applications.

Answer (score -4):

On your main screen, scroll left most, where you can see News, weather etc...
Scroll down on this page, and you can see an "EDIT" option
click on this and you can add "Battery" option.
Once done, the left most screen will show the battery level of iphone as well as connected bluetooth devices